# Pgpool 2 with AWS Aurora: dealing with replication lag

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, pgpool

A `Pgpool 2`(v. 4.3.1) is running in the `streaming_replication` mode with `load_balance_mode = on`. `PostgreSQL` is provisioned by AWS Aurora.

According to Pgpool 2 [documentation](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-4.3.1/en/html/runtime-config-running-mode.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-STREAMING-REPLICATION-MODE), in `streaming_replication` mode `PostgreSQL` is responsible for replicating data in each server. To deal with a possible replication lag a set of additional configuration parameters can be set: `sr_check_period`, `delay_threshold`. If the actual delay exceeds the configured value, `Pgpool 2` stops routing queries to reader DB instances.

However, in the Amazon Aurora [example](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-4.3.1/en/html/example-aurora.html) it is said that `sr_check_period` should be set to 0 (disabled) as Aurora does not expose the necessary functionality.

So the **question** is how to deal with the replication lag issue? Should I look to use the [Snapshot Isolation mode](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-4.3.1/en/html/runtime-config-running-mode.html#GUC-SNAPSHOT-ISOLATION-MODE) for `Pgpool 2`? Or there is a better approach I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replication lag issue will be tackled from multiple fronts, including validating if the existing AWS Aurora cluster corresponds to our needs, as well as application-level transaction optimization.
In addition, I came up with a workaround that tells `Pgpool 2` which queries should not be load balance.
As per Pgpool 2 documentation

> If you don't want a query that qualifies for the load balancing to be
> load balanced by Pgpool-II, you can put /*NO LOAD BALANCE*/ comment
> before the SELECT statement.

To work with the database our application uses the `Spring Data JPA` with `Hibernate`. The later one allows to add custom comments via the query hint `@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_COMMENT, value = "NO LOAD BALANCE")`.

Though, to make it work the session-wise property `hibernate.use_sql_comments` should be set to `true`. The drawback is that Hibernate will add default comments(which are the actual SQL queries) to every query it sends to DB making it twice as big. Hence, may degrade the performance. To avoid this I decided to override the method responsible for applying the hints and comments: `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect#addSqlHintOrComment`

```
@Override
public String addSqlHintOrComment(String sql, QueryParameters parameters, boolean commentsEnabled) {

    // Keep this here, rather than moving to Select.  Some Dialects may need the hint to be appended to the very
    // end or beginning of the finalized SQL statement, so wait until everything is processed.
    if (parameters.getQueryHints() != null && parameters.getQueryHints().size() > 0) {
        sql = getQueryHintString(sql, parameters.getQueryHints());
    }
    if ("NO LOAD BALANCE".equals(parameters.getComment()) || (commentsEnabled && parameters.getComment() != null)) {
        sql = prependComment(sql, parameters.getComment());
    }

    return sql;
}
```

The updated `if` statement checks if the `NO LOAD BALANCE` is present and prepends the query if so even the `hibernate.use_sql_comments` property is `false`.
Set `spring.jpa.database-platform` property to use the extended custom Dialect.

The last thing is wrapper `@NoLoadBalanceQuery` annotation around the `@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_COMMENT, value = "NO LOAD BALANCE")` - to make it easier to use for other devs.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@QueryHints
@Inherited
public @interface NoLoadBalanceQuery {

    @AliasFor(annotation = QueryHints.class, attribute = "value")
    QueryHint[] value() default {
            @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_COMMENT, value = "NO LOAD BALANCE")
    };
}
```